# c cannot create executables configure script

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gcc, configure

Executed command:

```
bash configure \
--enable-option-checking=fatal \
--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu \
--host=i686-linux-android \
--target=i686-linux-android \
--disable-warnings-as-errors \
--enable-headless-only \
--with-jdk-variant=normal \
--with-jvm-variants=client \
--with-cups-include=$CUPS_DIR \
--with-devkit=$ANDROID_DEVKIT \
--with-debug-level=release \
--with-freetype-lib=$FREETYPE_DIR/lib \
--with-freetype-include=$FREETYPE_DIR/include/freetype2 \
--with-boot-jdk=/root/java-se-9-ri/jdk-9
```

configure.log:

```
   configure:34583: $? = 0
    configure:34572: /root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/i686-linux-android/bin/gcc -v >&5
    Using built-in specs.
    COLLECT_GCC=/root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/i686-linux-android/bin/gcc
    COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/lto-wrapper
    Target: i686-linux-android
    Configured with: /s/ndk-toolchain/src/build/../gcc/gcc-4.6/configure --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --target=i686-linux-android --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-gmp=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpfr=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-mpc=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-cloog=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-isl=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --with-ppl=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/temp-install --disable-ppl-version-check --disable-cloog-version-check --disable-isl-version-check --enable-cloog-backend=isl --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm' --disable-libssp --enable-threads --disable-nls --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libstdc__-v3 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --disable-shared --disable-tls --disable-libitm --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=intel --with-fpmath=sse --enable-initfini-array --disable-nls --prefix=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix --with-sysroot=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/sysroot --with-binutils-version=2.21 --with-mpfr-version=3.1.1 --with-mpc-version=1.0.1 --with-gmp-version=5.0.5 --with-gcc-version=4.6 --with-gdb-version=7.6 --with-python=/usr/local/google/home/andrewhsieh/mydroid/ndk/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/python-config.sh --with-gxx-include-dir=/tmp/ndk-andrewhsieh/build/toolchain/prefix/include/c++/4.6 --with-bugurl=http://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html --disable-bootstrap --disable-libquadmath --enable-plugins --enable-libgomp --disable-libsanitizer --enable-gold --enable-graphite=yes --with-cloog-version=0.18.0 --with-ppl-version=1.0 --enable-eh-frame-hdr-for-static --program-transform-name='s&^&i686-linux-android-&' --enable-gold=default
    Thread model: posix
    gcc version 4.6 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC)
    configure:34583: $? = 0
    configure:34572: /root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/i686-linux-android/bin/gcc -V >&5
    gcc: error: unrecognized option '-V'
    gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:34583: $? = 1
    configure:34572: /root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/i686-linux-android/bin/gcc -qversion >&5
    gcc: error: unrecognized option '-qversion'
    gcc: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
    configure:34583: $? = 1
    configure:34603: checking whether the C compiler works
    configure:34625: /root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/i686-linux-android/bin/gcc  -fno-short-enums -D__GLIBC__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-psabi -march=i686 -msse3 -mstackrealign -mfpmath=sse -fPIE --sysroot=/root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/sysroot   -fno-short-enums -D__GLIBC__ -D_GNU_SOURCE -Wno-psabi -march=i686 -msse3 -mstackrealign -mfpmath=sse -fPIE --sysroot=/root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/sysroot  -Wl,--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -fPIE --sysroot=/root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/sysroot conftest.c  >&5
    /root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: --unresolved-symbols=ignore-all: unknown option
    /root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: use the --help option for usage information
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
    configure:34629: $? = 1
    configure:34667: result: no
    configure: failed program was:
    | /* confdefs.h */
    | #define PACKAGE_NAME "OpenJDK"
    | #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "openjdk"
    | #define PACKAGE_VERSION "jdk9"
    | #define PACKAGE_STRING "OpenJDK jdk9"
    | #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "build-dev@openjdk.java.net"
    | #define PACKAGE_URL "http://openjdk.java.net"
    | /* end confdefs.h.  */
    |
    | int
    | main ()
    | {
    |
    |   ;
    |   return 0;
    | }
    configure:34672: error: in `/root/mobile-jdk9':
    configure:34674: error: C compiler cannot create executables
    See `config.log' for more details
```

Comment: Have you installed the `build-essential` package? Looks like the lack of a C compiler.

Comment: Yes. Also `which gcc` returns `/usr/bin/gcc`

Comment: It looks like the issue is that the Android toolchain's `ld` doesn't support the `--unresolved-symbols=ignore-all` option ?

Comment: pretty sure a configure script should be executed by `sh`, not `bash`, or, alternatively by `bash --posix`

Comment: @waltinator the logs show the version of GCC being used, “gcc version 4.6 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC)”, and its path, `/root/jdk9mobile/android-ndk-r10b/generated-toolchains/android-x86-toolchain/i686-linux-android/bin/gcc`, so it can’t be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this by using toolchain for arm linux-androideabi

Used `--host=arm-linux-androideabi` `--target=arm-linux-androideabi` instead.

https://openjdk.java.net/projects/mobile/android.html